# Add button in a view to update entity reference on the user record

Tags: views, entities, users

I have a View, which is a table of nodes. I want one of these columns to be a button, and on clicking that button a field, which is an entity reference, on the user profile gets updated with a reference to the node of the row.

In other words, let's say I have a content type of fruit. The table has rows of fruit names, the user clicks the button on the banana row and an entity reference field on that users profile gets updated with a reference to the banana record. So now we know that user likes bananas.

What would be the best way to go about this?

(By the way I have looked at Bulk Views Operations, but it doesn't seem suitable without additional programming, and having something ajax based where the user can make the update without leaving the table would be the nicest solution).

Comment: I'm not sure anything that specific is going to exist (maybe something with rules?), a programmatic solution might be the only way to attack this

Comment: Thanks Clive. One way I have to investigate a bit more is I think there is a way to include a webform within a view, so that might be a way. I try to avoid programming in Drupal because for me doing programming when using Drupal is missing the point of using Drupal. There are so many ways to do things I'm sure there must be a good solution to this!

Comment: One way to do it might be by using the Rules Link module, which allows the creation of links that trigger Rules. I could pass the node reference in the link.